# Why is $wp_query->post unset during 404?

Tags: wordpress

I am using a plugin called Connections. When a 404 occurs (for good reason, i.e. a page that doesn't exist is accessed via the browser) then the custom post callback filter, specified in the plugin's code breaks, as `$wp_query->post` is unset. We get the complaint **Trying to get property of non-object** when `$wp_query->post->ID` is accessed. As you would expect.

I have disabled all other plugins and gone back to Twenty Fifteen theme but the issue still occurs. On a clean install the problem doesn't occur. This doesn't make sense to me. If it's not a plugin or theme issue and it's not in the Wordpress core then where is the issue? A corrupt database? (everything else seems to be working fine).

The filter callback is here:

```
public static function filterPostTitle( $title, $id = 0 ) {
   global $wp_query, $post, $connections;

   // ADDED: If I add this line the problem goes away.
   if ( is_404() ) return $title;

   // Whether or not to filter the page title with the current directory location.
   if ( ! cnSettingsAPI::get( 'connections', 'connections_seo', 'page_title' ) ) return $title;

   // If I uncomment the next two lines and comment out the following line of code, then the problem also goes away.
   //$post_id = get_queried_object_id();
   //if ( ! is_object( $post ) || $post_id != $id || ! self::$filterPermalink ) return $title;

   if ( ! is_object( $post ) || $wp_query->post->ID != $id || ! self::$filterPermalink ) return $title;
```

If I add the following check at the start of the function then the problem also goes away (again as we'd expect):

```
if ( ! isset( $wp_query->post ) || ! isset( $wp_query->post->ID ) ) return $title;
```

I have printed out backtraces to give me clues, however the backtraces don't seem to give many clues as the global variable $wp_query is at fault. This is another reminder why globals are bad practise... a very poor show for Wordpress. Globals make debugging a nightmare. Where is the global variable changed? We don't know.

The filter callback is set up as follows:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', array( __CLASS__, 'filterPostTitle' ), 10, 2 );
```

The developer of the plugin (maybe rightly so) thinks the problem lies outside of his plugin.

**QUESTION:**
Why is $wp_query->post unset at the time of the callback being triggered? Should $wp_query->post always be set by the time a 'the_title' filter callback is triggered?

As you may guess I am fairly new to Wordpress. It's mostly fantastic... not a fan of the global variables though... a big no-no.

Comment: Note that within the filter callback the global variable $post is set but $wp_query->post is not (during a 404).Should $post always be equal to $wp_query->post?

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason to call `global $wp_query` or `global $post` in the `the_title` filter...

Comment: @mevius What would you use instead to access these items? Are there member functions for this? I saw someone mention get_queried_object_id(). Again this is the problem with globals... if they are available then people use them. They shouldn't be set at all. If you HAVE to due to limitations in the architecture you are using at least call them something like __DONT_USE_DIRECTLY_wp_query that way people wouldn't call __DONT_USE_DIRECTLY_wp_query->post but would use the correct member function.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the point of the filter at all...In each case, the default `$title` is being returned (unless there's more to that method that you haven't shared). In other words, the filter is redundant, because it's not actually filtering anything. If the method is actually filtering the title somehow, I'd like to see the rest of the method, and see a plain-english translation of what the method is trying to do.

Comment: The point of this filter should only be to take the default title, filter/modify it as needed, and return the title back to WordPress.

Comment: @mevius Thanks for your help so far. The code is too large to add to a comment on here. What is the best way in comments to show you the code? Dropbox share or what? Thanks.

Comment: @mevius Ok... the code is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/24afwnj4k3t6bp2/stackoverflow33283211.php?dl=0 I can't give you the plain English as I didn't write the code. It is part of the Connections plugin (file class.seo.php).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still not sure what that check is actually there for. `$post` should be an object during `the_title` filter, no matter if a post is returned or a 404 is shown (so `is_object( $post )` seems redundant)...`$wp_query` should be `NULL` if you're on a 404 page, since there's no actual query object. Otherwise, I have no idea when `$wp_query->post->ID` wouldn't be equal to the `$id` passed to the filter. Honestly, I'd remove that check in favor of using `if ( !get_queried_object() ) return $title;`.

Comment: @mevius Thanks again. Your input has been extremely useful and saved me a lot of headaches. I've passed your comments on to one of the developers. [link](http://connections-pro.com/support/topic/404-gives-error-in-class-seo-php/page/2/#post-351565) On a positive I came away from this issue knowing a lot more about Wordpress! Result :-)

Comment: Cheers, Mike. Glad to hear it.

Comment: The plugin developer has done the update and the issue is now fixed. Thanks to Steven from http://connections-pro.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that `$wp_query->post` is unset during a 404...but rather that it's never set at all. In fact, `$wp_query->post` is unset for all new instances of `WP_Query`, when it is initialized. Let's [look at the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7771205935c799aa19fa2a178ed11b6b9de738a6/wp-includes/query.php#L1402):

```
/**
 * Initiates object properties and sets default values.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 * @access public
 */
public function init() {
    unset($this->posts);
    unset($this->query);
    $this->query_vars = array();
    unset($this->queried_object);
    unset($this->queried_object_id);
    $this->post_count = 0;
    $this->current_post = -1;
    $this->in_the_loop = false;
    unset( $this->request );
    unset( $this->post );  // Always unset
    unset( $this->comments );
    unset( $this->comment );
    $this->comment_count = 0;
    $this->current_comment = -1;
    $this->found_posts = 0;
    $this->max_num_pages = 0;
    $this->max_num_comment_pages = 0;
    $this->init_query_flags();
}
```

Next, a [query is parsed](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7771205935c799aa19fa2a178ed11b6b9de738a6/wp-includes/query.php#L1877), and if there's an error:

```
if ( '404' == $qv['error'] )
    $this->set_404();
```

The 404 status is set, and `$wp_query->post` is never populated/set.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Huge thanks for educating me on this.I'm just waiting for the plugin developer to respond (I've notified him of your answer). He's been really helpful so far. It benefits us all to understand what is happening in order that we can improve the Wordpress experience.